# Building a class to deserialize json to when one properties can be of two different types

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json.net

I have some Json that I want to parse to a c# object that can come through like this:

`{
"SomeObject" : {
    "name" : "something",
    "birthMonth" : "may"
    }
}`

Or Like this:

`{
"SomeObject" : {
    "name" : "something",
    "birthMonth" : 5
    }
}`

Is there a way I can model my SomeObject class so that the birthMonth property can be a string or an integer?

Comment: It wants to be a string, let it be a string.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use `dynamic` keyword.

```
public class SomeObject {
    public string name {get;set;}
    public dynamic birthMonth {get;set;}
}
```

But better way probably is to use some json (framework dependent) technique to transform `may` value to 5. For instance in `newtonsoft.json` there is an variant is to use  your own implementation of `JsonConverter`.

Here is an example: 
[How to implement custom JsonConverter in JSON.NET to deserialize a List of base class objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030538/how-to-implement-custom-jsonconverter-in-json-net-to-deserialize-a-list-of-base)